# Dither in CSS Gradients

Tags: css, gradient

I am using a CSS Gradient on a site that stretches across the browser. Unfortunately you can see banding.

I know within graphics programs such as Photoshop you can apply dithering to a gradient thus smoothing the gradient out.

Is there anyway to apply dithering to a CSS gradient either with additional CSS or even Javascript?

Comment: CSS gradients do not support dithering, it really depends on rendering engine. But you can generate gradient background image programmaticaly with canvas, which allows to implement dithering.

Comment: @Klaster_1 - Interesting. If you would like post an answer with a canvas example.

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer background images to css gradients at this point in time.  There are still many users out there with IE versions that don't do them, or can't do them properly.  This will also enable you to solve your banding problem - css doesn't support dithering/gradient antialias.

Comment: I am not worried about IE. In fact I officially support IE 10+ for my sites at this point. IE 9 and below is just too much of a pain and the number of users who are using those browsers (for my clients) is low and continues to drop.